# How to set a delay between fadeout and fadein

Tags: jquery

I am writing a site with 4 divs. When a link is clicked, the showing div is supposed to fade out and the new one fade in. The problem is that they are doing that at the same time, so the div that is fading in appears below the one that is fading out until the fadeout is complete. How do I make one happen after the other. Here is my jquery:

```js
function fadeAll() {
 $("#homediv").fadeOut(800);
 $("#affiliatediv").fadeOut(800);
 $("#merchantdiv").fadeOut(800);
 $("#aboutusdiv").fadeOut(800);
 $("#contactusdiv").fadeOut(800);
}
$(".affiliatelink").click(function() {
 fadeAll();
 $("#affiliatediv").fadeIn(3000);
})
$(".homelink").click(function() {
 fadeAll();
 $("#homediv").fadeIn(3000);
})
$(".merchantlink").click(function() {
 fadeAll();
 $("#merchantdiv").fadeIn(3000);
})
$(".aboutlink").click(function() {
 fadeAll();
 $("#aboutusdiv").fadeIn(3000);
})
$(".contactlink").click(function() {
 fadeAll();
 $("#contactusdiv").fadeIn(3000);
})
```

There is probably a cleaner way to do that, but I am new to jquery and was quite proud of myself for making this work.

Thank you for your help. I know that there are similar questions, but I could not find any that seemed to help. I did look.

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery.fadeOut gives you the possibility to declare a ["complete" callback function][1].

You need something like:

```js
function fadeAll(callback) {
    var $allDivs = $("#homediv, #affiliatediv, #merchantdiv, #aboutusdiv, #contactusdiv");
    $allDivs.fadeOut( 800, "swing", callback);
}

$(".affiliatelink").click(function() {
    fadeAll(function(){
        $("#affiliatediv").fadeIn(3000);
    });
});

//etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fadeOut` takes 0.8s to complete. You need your fadeIn to start after that.

Just use setTimeout function.

```
$(".contactlink").click(function() {
    fadeAll(); // All will start simultaneously and take 0.8s
    setTimeout(function(){

       $("#contactusdiv").fadeIn(3000);
     }, 800);  // After 0.8s, execute the function. (which contains the fadeIn call)
});
```

This should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, after posting this I found the .delay(time) function. Forget I asked.

Answer (score 0):

fadeOut by definition can accept a function which is executed after the fadeOut animation is completed. You can modify your fadeAll to look something like this:

```
function fadeAll(elementToFadeIn) {
    $("#homediv #affiliatediv #merchantdiv #aboutusdiv contactusdiv").fadeOut(800, function() {

        elementToFadeIn.fadeIn(3000);
    });
}
```

This will provide modularity to your code.